# How to match a list of words in a column in R and return into a separate dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of genes. I want to extract all rows containing the list of genes in column "gene" from a dataframe. The genes names are not unique in the dataframe.

```
list_of_genes <- c("XYZ", "CFD", "TEY")
```

Example Dataframe

| chr | pos | ID | gene |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 467 | ENS177287 | XYZ |
| 3 | 775765 | ENS177288 | CFD |
| 4 | 78623 | ENS177289 | TEY |
| 4 | 235423 | ENS177290 | TEY |
| 3 | 30909 | ENS177291 | CFD |
| 1 | 368163 | ENS177292 | XYZ |
| 6 | 354346 | ENS177293 | JGK |
| 2 | 98998 | ENS177294 | ROJ |

I tried subsetting the data but it only works for 1 gene name.

```
subset(df, df$gene=="XYZ")
```

Should I do a for loop? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: ```df %>% filter(gene %in% list_of_genes)``` or ```subset(df, df$gene %in% list_of_genes)```

Comment: Both of them work perfectly. Thank you.